# Stuck on trimming a CSS sprite

Tags: html, css

I have recently implemented a CSS sprite on the following webpage: (https://www.georgefox.edu/college-admissions/apply/transfer/index.html). (If you scroll down you will see what I am talking about below the "The process is easy" header. Before the update that was recently pushed to our CMS, the sprite worked perfectly. While I could roll back the update, my university wouldn't like that since we upgraded bootstrap and several other technologies.

Now, the sprite is showing numbers on the left and right side when it really should just show on the left side normally. I am trying to fix it with Pseudo-elements and classes but my attempts have yielded little to no progress. I tried using several background selectors in pseudo elements such as background-size, background-position, etc. A screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Thank you so much for any and all help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copy your `HTML` and `CSS` from your site and made few `CSS` change. You have to move your css sprite image css from `li` to `li:before` tag that will resolve your issue.

**Add Below CSS to apply CSS sprite on li:before**

```
.process-section ol li:before {
  background-image: url(http://www.georgefox.edu/college-admissions/apply/xtransfer-list-numbers.png.pagespeed.ic.NLZLYGEjg8.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
}
```

**Replace Below CSS in your style sheet**

```
.process-section ol li.two:before {
    background-position: -750px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.three:before {
    background-position: -1500px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.four:before {
    background-position: -2250px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.five:before {
    background-position: -3000px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.six:before {
    background-position: -3750px 0;
}

.process-section ol li {    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 45px;    
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**Remove `Background-position` css for first item we don't need that.**

```
.process-section ol li.one {
    background-position: 0 10px;
}
```

**Remove `background: none` from `.process-section ol ul li` and add below CSS to hide `:before` from child `li`.**

```
.process-section ol ul li:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.p-2 {
    padding: 0.5rem !important;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

.process-section ol {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.process-section ol li.two:before {
    background-position: -750px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.three:before {
    background-position: -1500px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.four:before {
    background-position: -2250px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.five:before {
    background-position: -3000px 0;
}

.process-section ol li.six:before {
    background-position: -3750px 0;
}

.process-section ol li {    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 45px;    
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.process-section ol li:before {
  background-image: url(http://www.georgefox.edu/college-admissions/apply/xtransfer-list-numbers.png.pagespeed.ic.NLZLYGEjg8.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    line-height: 21px;
}

.process-section strong {
    font-family: TradeGothic;
    font-size: 20px;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.process-section ol ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.process-section ol ul li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: inherit;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.process-section ol ul li:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="border p-2 process-section">
<ol>
<li class="one"><strong>Apply</strong>&nbsp; <br>A complete application includes:
<ul>
<li>Application form (available <a href="../index.html">online</a> or via the <a href="https://apply.commonapp.org/Login">Common Application</a>)</li>
<li>500-word personal statement</li>
<li>One letter of recommendation (from anyone who is not a family member)</li>
<li>Official college transcripts (from every school you’ve attended)</li>
</ul>
We are generally looking for a cumulative college GPA of 2.6 or better. We’ll call you personally soon after receiving your completed file with an admissions decision.</li>
<li class="two"><strong>File</strong>&nbsp; <br>We need your FAFSA information. You can submit this online at <a href="https://fafsa.ed.gov/">fafsa.ed.gov</a>.</li>
<li class="three"><strong>Review</strong>&nbsp; <br>Look over your financial aid package. After you’re admitted, we’ll use your FAFSA information to mail a financial aid award letter to you. We don’t have a due date for financial aid. As long as we are accepting applications for a semester, financial aid is available for students.</li>
<li class="four"><strong>Deposit</strong>&nbsp; <br>Submit your <a href="../../scholarships/enrollment-deposit.html">$300 enrollment deposit</a>. This secures your spot at George Fox.</li>
<li class="five"><strong>Register</strong>&nbsp; <br>Sign up for classes. All transfer students will register for classes at an event called <a href="../../visit/genesis.html">Transfer Genesis</a>. If you can’t make it, don’t worry. We’ll contact you and schedule an alternate registration appointment.</li>
<li class="six" style="border-bottom: 0;"><strong>Connect</strong>&nbsp; <br>If you have questions, don’t hesitate to contact us at <a href="tel:+15035542271">503-554-2271</a>.</li>
</ol>
</div>
```